# Live Server is stopped

Tags: atom-editor

I installed Atom for the very first time and then installed atom live server. I tried to launch the live server but every time it shows [Live Server] Live Server is stopped. Can someone suggest any method to start it, please.

Comment: Please provide all steps needed to reproduce the problem from scratch

Comment: Look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .atom-live-server.json file from project directory. OR restart your atom editors.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the web page files into a different a location and try open folder in a new window in atom.